# Modifying controls in a DOM window

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Disclaimer: I am new to ASP.net development and may be using some words incorrectly.

I am using the plugin jquery.DOMwindow.js, source is here: http://swip.codylindley.com/jquery.DOMWindow.js

In my page 'home.aspx', I am opening a page that will have some asp:CheckBox controls on it.  Those controls are on my 'DOMexample.aspx' page.

```
<a href="DOMexample.aspx" class="fixedAjaxDOMWindow" runat="server"> 
Check some check boxes. </a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.fixedAjaxDOMWindow').openDOMWindow({
            loaderImagePath: '../../images/ajax-loader.gif',
            height: 1200,
            width: 870,
            borderColor: '',
            borderSize: '0',
            overlayColor: '#000',
            overlayOpacity: '23',
            loader: 1,
            loaderHeight: 16,
            loaderWidth: 17,
            modal: 1,
            eventType: 'click',
            windowSource: 'ajax',
            windowHTTPType: 'get',
            windowPadding: 0

        });    
    </script>
```

On 'DOMexample.aspx', I have some check boxes that, when checked, will display a dropdown next to it.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chOptions" Text="Options" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddOptions" runat="server" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckSessionTimeout();
    chOptions.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.chOptions_CheckedChanged);
    ddOptions.Items.Add("Select Option Level");
    ddOptions.Visible = false;

}

void chOptions_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chOptions.Checked == true)
        ddOptions.Visible = true;
    else
        ddOptions.Visible = false;
}
```

My problem is, when I try to start debugging, I am able to pull up my DOM window, but when I check that box, it seems like the browser is trying to load 'DOMexample.aspx' in the whole browser (as opposed to refreshing the controls in the DOM window).

Comment: What is the world is `openDOMWindow`?

Comment: Looks like you are adding postback events!

Comment: @epascarello I just noticed I am using a jQuery plugin: jquery.DOMwindow.js and using the example code here: [link](http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html)

Comment: The problem is you are adding postback events so it will replace the page. You need to somehow convert your code over to Ajax calls.

Comment: @epascarello I haven't looked into it yet, but is it possible to modify controls (*.Visible = false) through Ajax calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to approach my problem through javascript, because if I were to modify the controls in the *.aspx.cs, it would require a postBack event that creates my problem (where the DOMwindow-page is loaded in the whole browser).

I created a javascript function 'toggleOptions' that will toggle the visibility of the drop down box.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chOptions" 
  onclick="toggleOptions();"
  Text="Options"
  runat="server" />

function toggleOptions() {
    var chOpt = $get('<%=chOptions.ClientID  %>');
    if (chOpt.checked) {
        $get('<%=ddOptions.ClientID  %>').style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        $get('<%=ddOptions.ClientID  %>').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

And further, I wanted to have the drop down load invisible, but still be rendered (it needs to be rendered in order for javascript to have access to it).  So in the 'head' section, I made a call to toggleOptions once the page has been successfully loaded using the jQuery .ready() function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        toggleOptions();
    });
</script>
```

Since the checkbox (chOptions) is initially rendered as unchecked, toggleOptions takes notice and hides ddOptions.